# Error: File b'tpu_train/metadata/results.csv' does not exist: b'tpu_train/metadata/results.csv' when running automl_gs on Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, automl

I came across this interesting [automl library](https://github.com/minimaxir/automl-gs), and was following [this guide](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sbF8cqnOsdzN9Bdt74eER5s_xXcdvatV#scrollTo=BT__brhBCvJu) to run the module on Colab. In my Colab instance, I have this code:

```
!pip install automl_gs
import os
from automl_gs import automl_grid_search
from google.colab import files
tpu_address = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
automl_grid_search(csv_path='20190419.csv',
                   target_field='UpdatedSiteName',
                   model_name='tpu',
                   tpu_address = tpu_address)
```

and this results in the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'tpu_train/metadata/results.csv' does not exist: b'tpu_train/metadata/results.csv'
```

I'm wondering if anyone on StackOverflow tried this `automl_gs` module on Colab and get it working. Based on the guide, it is supposed to create a folder `tpu_*` on its own, but it is creating the `*results.csv` file somewhere else as shown in the screenshot attached below.

[image: screenshot attached here].

Any tip/advice on how to overcome this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.